# SetForegroundWindow, AllowSetForegroundWindow & LockSetForegroundWindow

Tags: winapi, powershell, powershell-2.0

With a powershell code I try to change the position of a window (is works correctly) and put this windows "Always on top".

Please find below my code:

```
Import-Module C:/install/WASP/wasp.dll

Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class SFW {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
  }
"@


Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class Tricks {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@

Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class allowFor {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool AllowSetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
}
"@


Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class lockFor {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
     public static extern bool LockSetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
}
"@




do
{
    Start-Sleep -m 3000
    $allWindow = Select-Window Perso*
    if($allWindow)
    {
        foreach ($currentWindow in $allWindow) 
        {
            $positionWindow = WindowPosition $currentWindow
            foreach ($currentPosition in $positionWindow) 
            {
                #Loop on each windows
                if ( $currentWindow.title -match "\([0-9]*\)#" )
                {
                    # Retrieve windows ID
                    $id = $currentWindow.title.Substring($currentWindow.title.IndexOf("(")+1, $currentWindow.title.IndexOf(")")-$currentWindow.title.IndexOf("(")-1)
                    $allHUDWindow = Select-Window * | where {$_.Title -match "\($id\).*.txt"}

                    if($allHUDWindow)
                    {
                        foreach ($currentHUDWindow in $allHUDWindow) 
                        {
                            $currentForgr = [Tricks]::GetForegroundWindow()
                            if ( ($currentForgr -match $currentWindow.Handle -or  $currentForgr -match $currentHUDWindow.Handle) )
                            {
                                write-host "Pus currentHUDWindow in Front"


                                $hud =  (get-process -Id $currentHUDWindow.ProcessId).MainWindowHandle

                                [allowFor]::AllowSetForegroundWindow(-1)
                                [SFW]::SetForegroundWindow($hud)

                                #Modification de la position
                                Set-WindowPosition -X ($currentPosition.x-10) -Y ($currentPosition.y-30) -WIDTH ($currentPosition.width+20) -HEIGHT ($currentPosition.height+30) -Window $currentHUDWindow          
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} while(1)
```

But :

```
                                [allowFor]::AllowSetForegroundWindow(-1)
                                [SFW]::SetForegroundWindow($hud)
```

return me False.

From the documentation:

```
An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar button of the window to notify the user.
```

Do you know how can I force $currentHUDWindow to move in front ? And not only flashes the taskbar button ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please do not steal focus. Ever. No, your special case isn't special enough.

Comment: Maybe you can try calling a p/invoke of setfocus(hwnd) before the setforegroundwindows, but I can't test it... http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setfocus

Comment: You have to call AllowSetForegroundWindow from within the process with your processes id. Which probably means you will not be able to do it... which is by design. You should not be forcing windows to the foreground like that.